# How do I test a used domain name for Google penalties?

Tags: seo, domains, 301-redirect

If I launch a new website on a domain name previously used by someone else, and quickly learn that Google doesn't trust this domain (e.g. won't index pages due to past offenses), then can I simply relaunch the site on a new (unused) domain and set up 301 redirects? Or will the reputation of the 1st domain follow to the new one? Anyone tested this?

Background info: I'm launching a website in a my niche, and found an available domain name for the niche's primary keyword. The domain was used in the past, so I'm worried about purchasing a name that Google might associate with spam. I can't find any evidence of a Google penalty in the past, but you never know. I figured I'd buy the domain, launch the site, and cross my fingers that Google treats it like a new website (which it will be).

Comment: The only thing I'm thinking is the domain may go from bad to good in google's eyes if your website can prove to be valuable for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, build an awesome website by yourself with good content. Don't use any blackhat techniques which may give you a penalty.

You can do a little bit of research regarding your backlinks. Use a backlink tool to find them, and look for spammy links. In case you've found them, try to get the links removed from the website by contacting the webmaster.